# disable double click to zoom in autodesk viewer online

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

When selecting many elements in the Autodesk's online viewer, I double click accidentally and the model zooms to the element. I have to zoom and pan to the view I'm comfortable with again and it is very annoying. Is there a way to disable this functionality in the online viewer?

I found similar questions for the desktop apps (https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-forum/turn-off-wheel-double-click-zoom-extents/td-p/53144) but not the online viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fairly straightforward workaround for that: create a custom tool and absorb the double-click event. See that article for a start [Creating "Tools" for the View & Data API](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/03/creating-tools-for-the-view-data-api.html).

To absorb an event implement the corresponding handler and return `true`:

```
this.handleDoubleClick = function(event, button) {

  // ... do your stuff if needed ...

  // event handled 
  return true;
};
```